# Local Machine changes are not reflecting in container app response with docker volume command

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am trying to map docker container's folders to local machine folders using docker volume. I created an image and ran container. When the container started running, I made some changes in the local machine files, but my changes are not reflecting in the container's running application response.

**Dockerfile.dev**

```
#Specifying base image

FROM node:alpine

#Set Working directory

WORKDIR = "/webapp/"

#Copy the package json file
COPY ./package.json .

# Download the dependencies

RUN npm install

#Copy the remaining files

COPY ./ ./

#Start up command

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

**Creating an image** = docker build -f Dockerfile.dev .

**Creating and running application in the container** = docker run -p 3000:3000 -v folder_of_app:/webapp Image

Comment: There's an extra `=` in your `WORKDIR` statement that's being interpreted as part of the directory path.  But you should also consider why you don't want to run the code that's getting built into the image; I'd recommend deleting that `-v` option (and doing day-to-day development in Node outside of Docker).

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. That '=' was causing issue.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying to create volume doesn't work. You can check by inspecting docker volumes and checking the mount source. I would suggest using docker-compose. Create a docker-compose.yml file as below

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  node:
    container_name: docker-node
    image: docker-node-image
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - do your mapping here
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
     - 3000:3000
```

Now just do `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`.
However this is my suggestion, I am sure there must be a way to map volumes without using docker-compose

Comment: I was testing the docker volumes both through docker CLI and docker compose. But the issue was with '='  that I was putting in the WORKDIR statement in the docker file.